# How can I determine whether a specific file opens in windows and then closed

Tags: windows, file, unlock

I am working on windows 7 64 bit machine. 
How can I get list of files opened. Also, the list should change when a particular file is closed.

How to get a file close event:

1. when file is opened in a new process of file opener (like notepad,
   wordpad which opens file everytime in new process of wordpad)
2. when file is opened in a tab of file opener (like notepad++, which opens all files in new tab but there exist only a single process of notepad++ running).

I tried with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx), [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), openfiles, not able to catch the file close event on notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Use SysInternals' [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

It records all file and registry opens/reads/writes/closes. You can filter it to include or exclude specific patterns, file paths, programs, etc.

**Edit**

Process Monitor showing CloseFile when I close a tab in NotePad++:

[image: Screenshot of process monitor]

Comment: I used this, but it fails in case of notepad++, editplus i.e. applications which opens file in a tab with only a single process of application running.

Comment: @imp it does not fail; I'll edit my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: @can you please elaborate the settings to achieve this. Actually, as soon as file is closed, then I have to delete the respective file.

Comment: @imp settings, filter for "Process Name is notepad++.exe, Operation is CloseFile and Path is d:\test.txt". Without that you get loads of DLL and system files.